# how to extend an object just on one side along his own edges?

Tags: edit-mode

lets say i want to extend the object below just on his right side and it would not have the exact orientation at the x-axis like it has at the foto. so in other word: it should extend on the right side along his (long) edges (not at an axis). Is there a way to do that?

the edge slide does a similar thing i want but with that i just can make the object shorter but i want to have it longer on the right side.

PS: that object below is just an example not the one i am trying to work on

[image]

Comment: Press "e" to extrude, it should default to constrained axis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still use edge slide to do this.

- Select the end face (or its edges or vertices)
- <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.. edge slide
- Draw the face *inwards* a little way, making the piece shorter as you described in your post (this establishes the slide directions)...
- Now hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>, or tap <kbd>C</kbd> releasing the clamp. You should see rays extending the longitudinal edges.
- As long as you are holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>, you can slide the end face's vertices anywhere you like along those rays.

[image]

Unfortunately, snap doesn't work with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>. If you wanted that, too, I think you would have to break the operation up, separately moving components along Custom Orientations derived from the longitudinal edges.

Comment: thanks both for answers. the second one was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to input a distance?

Comment: @batFINGER In a a sense.. (you've got me looking).. If you're not set to 'Even' then the distance is expressed as a percentage of the length of the edges you're sliding along. Fair enough. If you are set to 'Even'  sliding _inwards_, you can numerically enter an absolute length _from_ the adjacent  loop. However, I can't get that to work outwards, directly.. so you would have to do it in 2 steps: take your loop out too far, and then  back, numerically,  to the desired gap.