# Extrude vertices along edges

Tags: extrude

I've been looking for answer on this site, but didn't find a solution, or dumb enough not to apply for my situation.
I need to extrude vertices along already created edges? Is there any way to do that?

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to extrude them into the said direction or if it's at all possible. But you can move them by double tappin g and holding alt. Then you can add a loopcut in the middle.

Comment: you are making your question difficult, do you just need to extrude vertices?

Comment: I need to extrude them along given edges. I tried moving them, but loop created after that has different topology, than i need.

Comment: Probably i need to create the new path for transformation, but i don't understand how to do it in a correct way.

Comment: I don't think you can do that

Comment: Thanks, moonboots, i will look for alternatives. Can You please advise how to do it alternatively, if any?

Comment: I told you how you can do it alternatively. That will work fine.

Comment: You can slide vertices along their edges out beyond an existing boundary if you release the clamp: see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/127747/35559)

Comment: Perfect! That's what i was looking for! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three different ways to do this currently. Options #1 and #2 only allow to specify distance factors relative to edge length. Option #3 should allow absolute units.

1. **Use vertex slide**: Press <kbd>G</kbd>,<kbd>G</kbd> twice to activate *Vertex Slide*, while the cursor is hovering the edge with the desired direction. Afterwards press <kbd>C</kbd> to deactivate clamping and allow extending beyond current position.

[image]

2. **Scale in relation to the other vertex**: Place you 3D cursor at the other end of the edge by snapping it to the vertex with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*. Change the *Transform Pivot* to the 3D Cursor and then scale the opposing vertex with <kbd>S</kbd>.

[image]

3. **Use a custom transform Orientation**: Select the edge with the desired direction. In the 3D View Properties Area from *Transform orientations* chango to local and press *+* to add a new one. Select it from the list (should be named `Edge`by default), then select your vertex and move it by using <kbd>G</kbd> then tapping twice the desired axis to move in local coordinates, in this case <kbd>Y</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd>.

[image]