# How to extrude tangent to the face only?

Tags: extrude

I create this pipe kind of thing from curve->bevel.
Then convert it to mesh. I want to continue slight extrusion at the end which looks in the continuation only. It is not along any axis. How to manage this extrusion?
[image]

Comment: if you cylinder is hollow I'm not sure you can except if you fill the face, then extrude, in that case don't forget to delete the inner face. But you could slide the selection along the edges with GG, then C to extend the slide, and add an edge loop where your edge loop was initially

Comment: Can also create a custom orientation (select the edges, add the custom orientation, then E and X).

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/127747/35559 to slide, followed by cutting in an edge loop.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. Custom orientation is still mystery for me @lemon

Comment: @Jehan, you can create an orientation from a selection: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/orientation.html#custom-orientations . and use it as new axis orientation.

Comment: @moonboots I think Robin's solution works well in this case.

Comment: @lemon let me try for it. :) I have to learn it so, why not now! Thanks for help.

Comment: yes that's was I was talking about (GG then C)  ;)

Comment: @lemon, not sure what you mean, I think it won't work if his cylinder is hollow (no face), and if it is not, the extrusion will follow the normals by default

Comment: @moonboots, it works even if hollow. Though, retesting it following your comment, the axis is not always the same (not always X, for instance). GG and C is not the same (no extrusion, a direction per vertex)... but could be what is wanted here. Don't know.

Comment: @moonboots ahh my bad... I thought that fill face was also in its continuation..

Comment: @lemon I can't make it work with a hollow circle, I don't know why

Comment: @moonboots, tested it again and does not work now... mmm...

Comment: @lemon, it never worked for me

Comment: @moonboots, ok... strange. Bezier curve, bevel, convert to mesh. From top view, rotate and apply rotation. Select a circle at extremity, etc. And here it works. Though effectively not in another configuration... never noticed that. So globally, you are right. But if you select only 3 vertices, it is ok (Blender see that as a face).