# How to extrude from hexagon but keep edge lines straight

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, workflow, extrude

[image]

See the picture. I extruded the area in the foreground, and then moved the vertex in the bottom left so that to make it just extends the line of the original hexagon, indicated by the red line.
But I don't want to do it by using my "eye", isn't there a way to adjust the vertex so it´s always on the red line?

I can´t seem to achieve this.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127743/how-to-extend-an-object-just-on-one-side-along-his-own-edges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use cursor for this
1-put it in center of hexagon (select 2 points and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> cursor to selected) and change transform pivot point to cursor
2-hit <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude then press <kbd>S</kbd> scale in towards the center(extrusion does transformation too so by pressing s or clicking, it just make the edge without moving it)
3-again use cursor and rotate 180 degrees along y axis that face you just made
4-<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to edge slide and adjust how far you want to go along red line you mentioned

[image]

Comment: Sorry I reproduced Step1 but from that point on I dont know what you mean, but that´s on me, Im very new to Blender. I know extrude and scale but what do you mean with "extrude and scale in near the center"?

Comment: i changed my answer . hope it help

Comment: i got it, very nice thank you!