# Extrude Flat Face Along Angle

Tags: faces, extrude

Seems simple enough, but I can't find the solution. How do I simply extrude this along it's current angle (axis)?

[image]

Like this example:
[image]

Comment: Also check out an [unclamped edge slide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/127747/35559) as an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom orientation.

1. Select the tilted face
2. Click the <kbd>+</kbd> button to add a custom orientation
3. Extrude the top face, choose your custom orientation and use the Y axis

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Jachym.. (as always, I'm open to correction, but..) I think the Custom Orientation is independent of the header orientation in play when it's created. If created from a face, it will _always_ be  Z-normal to the face. And there's no guarantee that Y will be parallel to any edge. (X and Y are always orthogonal, even in a skew face). It's more reliable to create an orientation from an _edge_  or any 2 verts, and use the Y, which will always be along it.

Comment: Hello Robin :). Thanks for the comment, you're right! Always learning new stuff here :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Press <kbd>1</kbd> for vertex selection mode
2. select one of vertices of this face
3. Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate it
4. Press <kbd>3</kbd> for face selection mode and select the face
5. Press <kbd>G</kbd> twice
6. Hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> and drag, then click
7. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
8. Create a loopcut
9. Press <kbd>1</kbd> for vertex selection mode
10. Re-select the corresponding corner to make it active
11. Activate vertex snapping

[image: 1]

11.press <kbd>G</kbd> and snap it to the copy you made before
11. Press <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>M</kbd>, then <kbd>B</kbd> to remove the temporary vertex.

[image: 2]