# Texture painting seams on joined/loose parts (same UVs, joined mesh)

Tags: texture-painting

I joined meshes together and unwrap the whole piece in one UV map. When I try to paint two loose parts there is an area that is not covered by brush but still visible on the mesh. I can unchek "occlude" and mask the part I dont want to paint but some parts are too imbricates to use this technique. I tried to increase bleed value but it seems to not changing anyting at all.

Any idea of how to get rid of these "seams"?[image: joined / lose parts seam texture painting blender]

Comment: Can you select faces around the seem and press **H** to hide them? I often get such seams when there's a perpendicular face underneath that cuts through the outer face a little.

Comment: I guess the faces act like masks at their junction point. In short: the part of a face that I can't paint because it is supposed to be hidden by another face is still visible on the mesh.
If I hide faces, I will not be able to see how I paint the joint between the separated faces.

Comment: You misunderstood me, I only ask that you hide 4 faces marked here: https://i.imgur.com/ucEV9DP.png and then take the screenshot again - I want to see what's underneath them.

Comment: Oh sorry :/ here is the screenshot : https://ibb.co/JrgDFF5

Answer (score 0):

You have artifacts caused by incorrect topology. Viewed from the side, your topology looks like this:

[image]

You have to correct the topology by joining the faces together, so that no face goes through another:

[image]

You could do it by first adding loop cuts (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>), and moving them as close to the extrusion as possible without going underneath it:

[image]

Then by aligning all vertices of those loopcuts with the extruding shape by selecting them, pressing <kbd>G</kbd> to move and then either <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> to move along only one axis and on the surface of the shape. If the faces of your shape aren't conveniently horizontal like mine, you can use [custom orientation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/210126/60486).

[image]

Now it's time to align middle vertices of the base with middle vertices of the extrusion: select them one by one, press <kbd>G</kbd> **twice**, and move them along the line.

[image]

Next step is to go to *Face Selection Mode* (press <kbd>3</kbd>), select a few faces and hide them (<kbd>H</kbd>). Now Select the faces of the base that you no longer need and press <kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>F</kbd> to remove them. Repeat this for the faces of the extrusion, that you also no longer need. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to unhide the faces.

[image]

Now switch to vertex snapping mode:

[image]

Go back to vertex selection mode (<kbd>1</kbd>), Press <kbd>Z</kbd>, then <kbd>W</kbd> for *wireframe* mode, select vertices of the extrusion, that are below the base's top and move them onto newly created vertices:

[image]

Press <kbd>A</kbd>, to select all vertices, then <kbd>M</kbd>, then <kbd>B</kbd> to remove doubles. Now your topology should be fixed. Press <kbd>Z</kbd>, then <kbd>S</kbd> to go back to *solid* mode.

Comment: It's not a problem of topology. This is a style of modelisation, called "stylized" or "hand painted" model. The point is to make a model with the minimum of polygons and if needed, some parts of the model are not connected to the principal mesh. This type of texturing and modeling is often used in games. The problem is about how we can see a part of a face but still not able to painting it.

Comment: @norab I'd say if changing the topology fixes the problem, then it was a problem of the topology. This doesn't mean the problem can't be fixed in other ways, and I too am interested to see if someone comes up with another solution.