# How to Extrude an edge then sliding it outward

Tags: extrude

How do i extrude an edge and then edge sliding it from the original direction it was extruded?
[[image: How to extrude that highlighted edge but to the direction of that red arrow 1]

How to extrude the edge highlighted in red but with the direction of the cyan arrow.
[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/127747/35559) help?

Comment: Thanks for answering. But i want to extrude the edge first then use that edge slide. So basically doing that edge slide but leaving that same edge on the face.

Comment: That sound like E, followed by GG(c) to me..just the same?

Comment: Yes E, GG, then C. But i want the direction of the GG be the same as doing GG, Then C, minus the E. I posted another image if that helps. :D

Comment: Here are solutions for a face that should also work for an edge: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210120/extrude-flat-face-along-angle/

Answer (score 5):

1. In Edit Mode, select the edge on the side in which direction you want to extrude and choose *Normal* in the *Transform Orientation* menu. EDIT: This step is obsolete since creating a custom orientation will automatically use the edge's orientation. I just did it to show it's pointing in the desired direction.

[image: parallel extrude 1]

2. In the *Transform Orientation* menu, create a new custom orientation by hitting the + symbol.

[image: parallel extrude 2]

3. Rename it to your likings (I've chosen 'parallel') and leave *Use After Creation* checked.

[image]

4. With the new *Transform Orientation* selected (if not, choose from the list), select the edge you want to extrude, hit <kbd>E</kbd> > <kbd>Y</kbd> to extrude it along the custom orientation. If it's not <kbd>Y</kbd>, hit <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>, whatever matches the correct orientation.

[image]

Comment: Only thing is that it's not necessary to choose normal transform orientation if creating and using custom one later.

Comment: Yes, you're right of course. I originally chose it to see if it points in the correct direction before creating a custom orientation. I'll edit and make it clear that this is not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

**1.** In edit mode, **select the edge** you want to extrude;

**2.** On the top bar, change the **Transform Mode** from ***Global*** to ***Local*** (This menu is right next to the Transform Pivot Point menu, on the top bar);

**3.** Press **E** to ***Extrude***;

**4.** Press ***Y*** (or X or whatever axis you want to extrude along);

**5.** Celebrate.

Comment: But the edge normal is perpendicular to the edge he wants to extrude, so neither _Local_ nor _Normal_ will work. What he wants to do is extrude parallel to the other edges so your solution won't work.

Comment: It does work as I have tested it here myself. Even though the edge is perpendicular to the face normal, the local transform mode maintains the edge axis orientation (in this case the Y axis) in the same direction of extrusion, as he wants.

Comment: The local orientation takes into account the orientation of the object. As long as the object isn't rotated in the direction he wants to extrude, it cannot work. If you create a plane and move one edge let's say in Y direction in Edit Mode to create a rhomboid, then the local orientation of the object stays the same as the global orientation. So if you want to extrude an edge in a direction that's not parallel to any axis, then your solution doesn't work. You say the edge maintains the local orientation, the problem is he wants to extrude in a different direction than the local orientation.