# How to slide and extrude

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges, extrude

I’ve been trying to slide and extrude a hexagon, but I can’t get past this simple problem. I tried to extrude an edge, but it extrudes without following the hexagon’s angle. So far, I’ve managed to do a vertex slide using <kbd>C</kbd> to clamp, but I cannot get this to work with extrude.

Here is a sketch of what I want to achieve.

[image]

EDIT:

As asked, I’m posting the result of the solution Marty Fouts suggested. I enabled shadows and perspective so you can understand what happens. What I did here was simply move the original hexagon edge up. Now you can see it unfortunately doesn’t intersect the shape, as intended.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). The fastest way would probably be to use a custom orientation.

Comment: Hi!   Thanks for your comment. However, I’m not sure I understand. Would you mind explaining a bit further?

Comment: Hey :). Almost the same case as here: [Extrude face along angle](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/210120/78972). In your case, select the two vertices to create the custom orientation.

Answer (score 8):

The trick is to use some supporting geometry. Rather than extruding, add a face and use the knife tool to make an additional edge:

[image: add a face]

[image: Use the knife too to add an edge]

If you use 'c' with the knife tool you'll get a perpendicular edge.

Now loop slide your new edge with 'C':

[image: starting the loop slide]

[image: after the loop slide.]

If you don't want to add and then remove faces, you can select the two edges that are adjacent to the edge you want to extend and subdivide them:

[image: subdivided adjacent face]

then use 'f' to connect the two new vertices:

[image: adding a new edge]

and do the loop slide:

[image]

Also, start the edge slide with 'gg' and then move the edge slightly before entering 'C' so that Blender knows which direction you want to extend in.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me with this.

However, there must be something I must have missed. When I lower the original hexagonal edge on the Z axis after doing those operations, I see that this edge isn’t intersecting between the original hexagon and the new outer edge. When looking at this shape using the Front View, it looks like a "J".

Sorry, it’s difficult to explain without a picture. 

Comment: Could you edit the original question and add some screenshots to it?

Comment: There you go. Please let me know what you think. Thanks! 

Comment: You are not using the knife tool the way I described, so you are creating a new edge that is adjacent to the original surface rather part of it.   You would probably be better off subdividing the two edges and then using f to join the two new vertices as in my second example.

Answer (score 7):

I don't *think* it would be possible to implement a general *Extrude* operator that would work the way you want. If there were more than 2 edges to be brought out, they might contradict one another.

Here's one way of using the shipped 'TinyCAD' add-on as an alternative to @Marty Fout's answers ... There are others, and this solution is certainly no better than his... (it's maybe even a bit nutty :D)

[image]

1. Use TinyCAD to create a vertex at the intersection of your two edges
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> put the cursor there, and ensure it's the Transform Pivot point
3. <kbd>E</kbd> extrude the facing edge and drop it with a right-click
4. <kbd>S</kbd> scale the extrusion towards the cursor.