# How can I increase the lenght of objects with precision?

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers, edit-mode, vertices

[image]

Hello, so I've build this house and noticed that the roof needs to be higher therefore the edges of the roof need more lenght. I don't wan't to destroy the roof and do it anew. So what would be the best way to increase the lenght precisely?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/127747/35559

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, selected all my edges of my roof, then  <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>C</kbd> to 60cm!