# How to slide vertices into the opposite direction in the exact same angle?

Tags: vertices, transforms, edges, topology, extrude

I'm trying to improve my modeling knowledge via modeling different cars but I always fail miserably shortly after modeling curved panels because I made bad topology, which I have zero experience with unfortunately. I thought the problem would be that I move the vertices on the X/Y/Z axis instead of sliding the vertices in the opposite direction of what is possible via pressing Shift + V.

What I would like to do:
[image]

Basically in the X and -Z direction without the angle of the edges changing. I would like to do this with the vertices as well as extruded edges.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I think you may find an answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/127747/35559). If that's what you need,we may close this question as a duplicate.. could you let us know, please?

Comment: Yes it's the one! Thank you you can close the question now!

Comment: Great! I think we can close then, thanks for the reply.